# What is the best efficient format to store a large SparseMatrix in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sparse-matrix

I have a `pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix` with 100k rows and 20M columns. What is the best format to save it as a sparse matrix in PySpark?

I found another post with a little different topic from a year ago, but the answers are not a solution to my question. 
[Link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645498/create-sparse-rdd-from-scipy-sparse-matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparse Matrix is a representation of data, that allows you to use less space in RAM memory during computations.

If you want to persist data you need to consider:

- `sequenceFile` format, where you put coordinates as the key and a non-zero value as the value.
- `parquet` format, where you save dense matrix, nevertheless parquet optimize repetitive values in columns, so it can nicely compress zeroes over the matrix. You can also extract a representation like `(row, column, value)` in columns and put all non-zero values there, then save in parquet format.